# Android Support4Demos - API 4+ Support Demos full project

Tags: android, project, demos

I want the full sample code for the Support4Demos. How can I download the full project?
i only saw some files here
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/index.html

But normally it should be in android-sdk/samples.

I have installed all samples for SDK API 7-13, revision 1 but still i can not find it in the samples folders.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look in [your-sdk-path]/extras/compatibility/v4 or v13 for the library and sample apps. You'll need to run javadoc to extract out html documentation on the source files.

More details here:
[Android Compatibility Library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)

Answer (score 4):

On my machine this demo was in [my-sdk-path]/extras/android/support/Samples

Answer (score 0):

I found it in `[my-sdk-path]/android-compatibility/v4` or `v13`